# 'AppSettings' object has no attribute 'STORE_TOKENS'

Tags: python, django, twitter-oauth, django-allauth

I have Object: **AppSettings** in `app_settings.py`

class AppSettings(object):
def **init**(self, prefix):
self.prefix = prefix

```
def _setting(self, name, dflt):
    from django.conf import settings

    getter = getattr(
        settings,
        "ALLAUTH_SETTING_GETTER",
        lambda name, dflt: getattr(settings, name, dflt),
    )
    return getter(self.prefix + name, dflt)

    @property
    def STORE_TOKENS(self):
        return self._setting("STORE_TOKENS", False)`
```

**And when it get requested in my** `models.py`

by:

`if app_settings.STORE_TOKENS and self.token and self.token.app.pk:`

getting attribute error saying!

**'AppSettings'** object has no attribute 'STORE_TOKENS'.

Answer (score 0):

In your settings.py you need to add this line :

```
STORE_TOKENS= True
```

Comment: still getting the same ERROR!

'AppSettings' object has no attribute 'STORE_TOKENS'

Answer (score -1):

Actually the problem was....I was trying to authenticate during the logged in django administration.